# BadRequest response string is wrapped in additional quotes

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api

In my ASP.Net REST controller I do the following:

```
return BadRequest("A problem happened!");
```

When calling this over HTTP I get the message as follows:

```
HttpResponseMessage response = await _httpClient.GetAsync(url);
if (!response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
{
    var errorMessage = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

But the value of the `errorMessage` is:

```
"\"A problem happened!\""
```

When I run through PostMan it doesn't include the quote marks even in the raw output view so I'm not sure if they are being added on for some reason, but I would rather avoid having to manually strip them.

I based my work on this other question where nobody seemed to have this issue: [BadRequest custom error message not returned to client?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49354057/badrequest-custom-error-message-not-returned-to-client)

Answer (score 0):

It is just a json string, you have to deserialize it

```
 var errorMessage = "\"A problem happened!\""; // "A problem happened!"
 var errMsg = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<string>(errorMessage); // A problem happened!
```